# dynamic url for $http.get in Angular, load data from a form into the url

Tags: angularjs

I've got an Angular controller

```
 myApp.controller('DateController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.date = {year: '2017', month: '08', day: '28'};
 });
```

I've got a second controller for the same module:

```
myApp.controller('rateList', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://api.fixer.io/2000-01-03')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.rates = data.rates;      
        });
 }]);
```

In my HTML I've got a form linked to that controller, and I successfully can change the values of $scope.date.  What I need now is to take the values from $scope.date and have those loaded into the url in the http call.
The example url I hardcoded was 2000-01-03. **But I do not want to use these hardcoded values, I wish to use the values from $scope.date**

Comment: Why not just append it? `"http://api.fixer.io/" + $scope.date.year +  "-" + $scope.date.month + "-" + $scope.date.day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
$http.get('http://api.fixer.io/' + $scope.date.year + '-' + $scope.date.month + '-' + $scope.date.day)
```

or better

```
var dateString =  $scope.date.year + '-' + $scope.date.month + '-' + $scope.date.day;

$http.get('http://api.fixer.io/' + dateString)
//your remaining code
```